# Replace file when downloading

Tags: javascript, html, file, download

Referring to this example: http://jsfiddle.net/m9nts8r1/

How can I update the content of `updatedText.xml` when pressing the 'Download' button, just as it does when the 'Save' button in any application?

In this case I just get another `updatedText (1).xml`, `updatedText (2).xml` and so on.

Moreover it would be nice if it was possible to specify the directory where the `updatedText.xml` is saved.

Has someone an idea?

Comment: Maybe you can try this lib http://pixelgraphics.us/downloadify/test.html which prompts the user to replace the file if that file already exists

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do this. Once the file is downloaded it is on your hard drive. Your web browser does not have the permission to access your file system (just imagine what a mess it would be if a website could look into your files or even change them). I guess you will unfortunately have to live with the newly created files or solve your problem with another technology.

Comment: You´re right. It would be fatal if someone else would change my files. I loaded the data on a database. Originally I wanted to avoid this, because I wanted to start a web application with only one click without the need of a database.

Comment: Did you know that there are multiple ways of saving data in the browser without the need for a webserver database? Check out http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage for more information

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in chrome browser

download extension from this link
https://github.com/zach-adams/downloads-overwrite-already-existing-files
"A chrome extension that sets all downloads to overwrite existing files instead of adding ' (1)', ' (2)', etc."
then add extension to chrome
this will solve your problem.

Comment: It would be useful for someone to have explained the downvote. Is the suggested plug-in not stable, or is the concept flawed as described by k-nut.

Comment: I think this is an excellent answer. One possible objection to it is that, since we're writing javascript, we can't expect every user of our website to have this installed, so it's not a solution for them. And indeed, the first answer to this thread is correct: we can't implement a solution for all users, because you can't just play around with files on the filesystem.

However, if (like me) you are only looking to overwrite files on your own filesystem, this works just fine.