# Saving div contents by overwriting an existing file

Tags: javascript

In a Windows environment, the following javascript function saves the contents of "mydiv" to "myfile.html"

```
function Save() { 
   var a = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("a"));  
   a.download = "myfile.html"; 
   a.href = "data:text/html," + document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML; 
   a.click(); 
}
```

My problem is that when I keep calling this function, it automatically renames
the saved file as myfile(1).html, myfile(2).html,... etc.
How can I force it to always overwrite the initially saved myfile.html, i.e, keep the same name?

EDIT: From the answers  below, it's clear that the browsers' policy does not allow overwriting the users' files, for security reasons. But it is possible for a user to save and overwrite the whole page with CTRL+S. So the question becomes: Is there a way to do the same with the contents of only a specific div?

Comment: Isn't that the default behaviour of the browser?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace file when downloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26606415/replace-file-when-downloading)

Comment: @traynor I understand that the browser normally does not have access to the user's filesystem, but what I have in mind is that "myfile.html" actually is user input data, .i.e, a parameter provided by the user, who is therefore responsible for the file name.

Comment: @traynor  Further, we can save the whole page with CTRL+S and overwrite an existing file. Then why not be able to do the same with the contents of a single div?

Comment: AFAIK, you can't affect filename with code once the download process starts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the window.showSaveFilePicker(), that will create a pop-up just like when you "save as" an image or something. It lets the user specify the name and location of the file they are saving, and for that reason it's the only way to overwrite a user file, because in other ways, where the user don't have control to what file exactly would be overwritten, it could open doors to malicious code.

For now it's an experimental technology (check compatibility [here](https://caniuse.com/?search=showSaveFilePicker)) and also might only be available in secure contexts (HTTPS), so maybe you don't want to use it in production still, but that's for you to judge

Here's an example of how you could use it in your case:

```
async function saveFile(content, type, name) {
    var blob = new Blob([content], { type: type });
    var opts = {
        suggestedName: name
    };

    var handle = await showSaveFilePicker(opts);

    // Write the blob to the file.
    var writable = await handle.createWritable();
    await writable.write(blob);
    await writable.close();
}
```

This function will take the content the downloaded file should have, the type of the file and a name (note the name is just a sugestion, and the user is free to choose how it'll download the file).
This function also can only be called by and event fired by an user (like the user clicking a button), else it won't work

Comment: Yes, the File System Access API is a nice solution. Thank you for suggesting this. Some links in case anyone else is interested: http://developer.chrome.com/articles/file-system-access  and http://css-tricks.com/getting-started-with-the-file-system-access-api/