# How to replace a file in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, save

The below function gets data written in an user dialog window and saves it on a file in JSON format. The save action is working fine. My problem is that each time the Save button is clicked, a new `my-download.json` is created in Downloads folder.

```
    saveJSON() {
    var saveData = (function () {
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        return function (data, fileName) {
            var json = JSON.stringify(data),
            blob = new Blob([json], {type: "octet/stream"}),
            url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            a.href = url;
            a.download = fileName;
            a.click();
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        };
    }());

    let smtpFrommtpHost = (document.getElementById("smtpFrom") as HTMLInputElement).value;
    let smtpDisplayName = (document.getElementById("smtpDisplayName") as HTMLInputElement).value;
    let smtpRecipients = (document.getElementById("smtpRecipients") as HTMLInputElement).value;


    var data = {      
        "From": smtpFrommtpHost, 
        "DisplayName": smtpDisplayName, 
        "Recipients":smtpRecipients, 
        d: new Date() 
    },
    fileName = "my-download.json";  
    saveData(data, fileName);
}
```

What I want to do is to replace `my-download.json`'s content if it already generated. How could I do it?
And another question would be how could I change the location where the file is saved? Let's say I'd like to be saved on C:\MyJOSN folder.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace file when downloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26606415/replace-file-when-downloading)

Comment: Thanks for reply! I'll check if it helps me.